# Is it possible to make Mocha wait for a Promise to resolve, which sets up the Express app?

Tags: javascript, express, promise, mocha.js

I am working on an older Express app and upgrading it to use a remote secrets storage service. Inside the app entry point I have something like:

```
getSecrets.then(secrets => {
    ...
    const app = express();
    // configure app...
    // start server...
});
```

Previously this was a synchronous operation and there was a `module.exports = app` which was required later in a required Mocha module.

Now when the tests run, of course this doesn't work. I have attempted to export the Promise and tried to make some tests wait for it, but not having much luck.

Does anyone have any recommendations on this? I don't really find anything out there quite like this.

The root issue is that the tests require the app to be set up so that `require` can do HTTP requests against the routes.

Is there some way to make Mocha wait for the Promise to resolve if I returned the `app`?

This app uses Gulp.

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var _ = require('lodash');
var gulp = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp'));

var config = require('../config.js').mocha;

// TODO: gulp-order is required to deal with some of the order-dependent
// tests

gulp.task(
  'mocha',
  'Runs mocha with NODE_ENV = env.NODE_ENV || \'test\'',
  function() {
    var mochaOptions = _.extend({}, config.options, {
      NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'test',
    });

    return gulp.src(config.src)
      .pipe($.order(config.src))
      .pipe($.cached('mocha'))
      .pipe($.spawnMocha(mochaOptions));
  }
);
```

The app is set to a global inside the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: Set up a separate app for Mocha to test with using the same routes/config defaults.